# How to grab an href using xpath after certain words appear in the class above

Tags: xpath

I want to grab: a) the Facebook page URL b) the Facebook page name from here:

```
<div class="desc">Example text</div>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/example" target="_blank" class="blank show-tooltip" data-tooltip="this is text">Example Facebook page Name</a>
```

Is there anyway XPATH can check for the `class='desc'` then return me what I need?

Answer (score 0):

First you need valid xml to work with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
 <div class="desc">Example text</div>
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/example" target="_blank" class="blank show-tooltip" data-tooltip="this is text">Example Facebook page Name</a>
</form>
```

Given that, this will work:

```
//div[@class = "desc"]/following-sibling::a/@href
```

Comment: this may need a predicate to restrict to first following sibling, ie. `//div[@class = "desc"]/following-sibling::a[1]/@href`